# how to read all the data using for loop

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
my code is connection.query('call addtion("'+tr+'","'+lat+'","'+long+'","'+sp+'","'+dat+'","'+start+'","'+stop+'",@phonenos,@nameofstop,@busstartstatus);SELECT @phonenos as PhoneNos;SELECT @nameofstop as NameOfStop;SELECT @busstartstatus as BusStartStatus',function(err,result){

console.log("connection.query('call addtion("'+tr+'","'+lat+'","'+long+'","'+sp+'","'+dat+'","'+start+'","'+stop+'",@phonenos,@nameofstop,@busstartstatus);SELECT @phonenos as PhoneNos;SELECT @nameofstop as NameOfStop;SELECT @busstartstatus as BusStartStatus'");
```

My question is i have

> 24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A,24245676856859870D0A,242457658658786870D0A

now its taking only lastdata ie,242457658658786870D0A

Comment: Your given data as string or array?

Answer (score 0):

If given data store in array then Use foreach loop like this

```
foreach($data as $str)
{
  echo $str."<br>";
}
```